# Add A Method To A Property Of A Class

Tags: vba

I am confused. I am new to VBA classes. I want to add multiple methods to a property of a class, or add properties to another property. I may not have the terminology correct?

I can add one property, but I want to drill down deeper.

For instance if I make a class person:

```
PersonClass.Features.Hair.Texture.Color
PersonClass.Features.Hair.Texture.Style
PersonClass.Features.Hair.Length
```

I am not sure how to go about this.

e.g.

```
MyClass.MyProperty.MyMethod1
MyClass.MyProperty.MyMethod2
MyClass.MyProperty.MyMethod3
```

or

```
MyClass.MyProperty.MyMethod1.MyMethod2
```

Comment: The example you provide is classes within classes.  So you would have a Person class which contains a Features class and so on.

Comment: How can I create a class within a class?

Comment: After creating the Features class, within Person you would have a property defined `As Features`.

Comment: VBA doesn't support defining classes within classes.  To do what you need to achieve you create all your classes independently.  Then to get the dot notation you must declare a property in a class which has a backing variable for the sub class. and so on.  So that you essentially have MyClass.MySubclass1Property.MySubclass2Property.MySubclass3Property.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is "composition" - the Excel object model has *dozens* of examples of this. By convention, when a property returns an object, it would be named after the class of that object, e.g. `Range.Font` yields a `Font` object.

Comment: One minor point is that `Features` typically implies a collection of `Feature` objects which isn't the case here.

Comment: @BrianMStafford that's a very very good point - naming (and more importantly, *consistency*) is critical in any API design, and indeed a pluralized name implies an object collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate the concepts mentioned in the comments:

**Main Form**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim p As Person
   Set p = New Person
   p.Features.Hair = "Red"
   MsgBox p.Features.Hair
End Sub
```

**Person Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Features As Features

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set m_Features = New Features
End Sub

Public Property Get Features() As Features
   Set Features = m_Features
End Property
```

**Features Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Hair As String  'this would actually be another class
                          'in your example

Public Property Get Hair() As String
   Hair = m_Hair
End Property

Public Property Let Hair(ByVal Value As String)
   m_Hair = Value
End Property
```

Comment: Consider *not* exposing a `Set` accessor for these (already-initialized) properties; you wouldn't want external code to be able to `Set person.Features = someOtherFeaturesObject`